# binding qt with ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, qt

Is it possible to bind QtRuby with ruby 192 on windows? If yes, how?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's considered to be a bit far-fetched at the moment (blog post: http://cyrusbuilt.net/wordpress/?p=294). At best you can run Ruby 1.8.7 with the latest patch level against Qt 4.6.1 (bundled with Qt4Ruby), you can take a look at these blog posts : http://tom.paschenda.org/blog/?p=43 and my blog post, http://dr1ku.posterous.com/qt-461-ruby-187-on-win32

Answer (score 0):

As of writing this answer qtbindings gem works ok with Ruby 1.9.2. Simply install Ruby via RubyInstaller, install DevKit, gem install qtbindings and everything will work.